# Microsoft jet database engine cannot open the file.''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis, ssis-2012

What is the possible solution for this? I force execute the SSIS Job

[image]

but the error encountered is

```
Microsoft jet database engine cannot open the file.''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission
```

What is solution for this I already change the security

[image]

This is the flow of the SSIS. The process of this is to update the data of the SQL Server coming from the MDB.

[image]

Comment: Do you have Access open?

Comment: HI @Steve I remote the server because I deploy the SSIS on that server, I checked on that server there has no MS ACCESS only(Word and Excel) but there is access database 2007 installed.

Comment: Does another user have the database open in Access?  How about another automation process?  (Automation can open exclusive as well.)  There's also a known bug with Windows Server having to do with lease times or some such.  You might Google that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm ever required to use a communal data source like this, especially if the tooling (Excel/Access) takes an lock when someone is just looking at the file, I find it beneficial to copy the file elsewhere for processing.

Before your Update Control Rate data flow, have a File System Task. Define it as a copy with overwrite/clobber/replace from `\\server\share\TDMAT TEST\TDMAT.mdb` (or whatever the obscured path is) to a local folder that SQL Server Agent/Service Account/SSIS credentialed account has read/write access to. I usually have a folder defined like `C:\ssisdata\data_domain\input`. So, copy TDMAT.mdb to C:\ssisdata\tdmat\tdmat.mdb.

Then, you have your JET connection managers reference the local file. Away goes your concurrent usage issues. The clever among you might question why we can copy a file that is "locked" but not read it and I can't tell you the why, just that this approach works.